# Calling future.result() multiple times

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm using Python's `ThreadPoolExecutor` to execute a function concurrently on different threads. The executed function returns an enum `PytestResult` and afterwards I'm logging the returned result and appending it to a database:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(self.vm_pool)) as executor:
            futures = {executor.submit(
                self.execute_test, test): test for test in self.test_pool}

            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                test = futures[future]

                failure_reason = None

                try:
                    result = future.result()

                    if result == PytestResult.PASSED:
                        logging.info(f'Test {test} passed')
                        status = TestStatus.PASSED
                    else:
                        logging.error(
                            f'Test {test} failed: {PytestResult[result]}')
                        status = TestStatus.FAILED
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f'Test {test} failed with exception: {e}')
                    status = TestStatus.EXCEPTION
                    failure_reason = str(e)
                finally:
                    logging.info(f'Updating test "{test}" status to "{status}"')
                    database.update_test_status(self.pipeline, test.id, status, failure_reason)
```

I want to check if all the futures returned a successful result, so I did this:

```
return all(future.result() == PytestResult.PASSED for future in futures)
```

However, I'm not sure if calling `future.result()` a second time is good practice, if the result is already cached/calculated or not. I know I can keep a track of the passed tests in a list, but I wanted to do a "one-liner" to easily check if all are successful.

Comment: `if future.done()` then collect the result. Once the Pool is empty check if all results pass the test

Comment: `Future.result()` does some error checking but that's about it.  Any long calculation would already be done before the worker calls `Future.set_result()`.  Don't worry about calling result() twice - the other things you're doing (storing data to a database, formatting a logging message) are certainly many times slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Future.result()` as many times as you like.

The result is stored on the `Future` object when completed and retrieving it multiple times with `.result()` does not recalculate it or perform any meaningful work.

The `concurrent.futures.Future` source code is pretty easy to read if you're interested in the internals of this:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L428